# How to give a Material 3 Button the same color in disabled state as in enabled state?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, material-design

I want to to create a Button that when disabled keeps the color of an enabled button (I then switch the button content from a text to a circular progress indicator). However I don't know how to "reference" the default colors. My idea is to use `ButtonDefaults` and override some values like this:

```
@Preview
@Composable
private fun ButtonSandbox() {
    Button(
        enabled = false,
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        onClick = {},
        colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
            containerColor = , // how to reference default for enabled button here?
            contentColor = , // how to reference default for enabled button here?
            disabledContainerColor = , // how to reference default for enabled button here?
            disabledContentColor = // how to reference default for enabled button here?
        )
    ) {
        CircularProgressIndicator(
            modifier = Modifier.size(ButtonDefaults.IconSize)
        )
    }
}
```

So, how can I reference the default colors of an enabled Button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default color for a Button is the material theme primary color, and content is the OnPrimary color.

You can just do :

```
@Preview
@Composable
private fun ButtonSandbox() {
    Button(
        enabled = false,
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        onClick = {},
        colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
            disabledContainerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary,
            disabledContentColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onPrimary,
        )
    ) {
        CircularProgressIndicator(
            modifier = Modifier.size(ButtonDefaults.IconSize)
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I had to add `color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onPrimary` to the `CircularProgressIndicator` otherwise it's not visible because it has the same color. How did you figure out the default color for the `Button`?

Comment: You can CTRL+ Click on an element to see it internal declaration